# Equivalent condition to $\cal {I}(\cal{Z}(f))=(f)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f$ be a polynomial of one variable on the field $k$, with degree $>0$. Show that $\cal {I}(\cal{Z}(f))=(f)$ if and only if $f$ is the product of distinct linear factors in $k[x] $.

Remark: $\cal{Z}(f)=\{v\in k:f(v)=0\}$ and $\cal {I}(S)=\{f\in k[x]:f(s)=0, \forall s\in S\}$.

Comment: Your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: I understand that $(f)\subset \cal {I} (\cal{Z}(f))$,  so I need to prove if $\cal{I} (\cal{Z}(f))\subset (f)$, then $f$ can be decomposed to linear factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v\in\cal{Z}(f)$ then $(x-v)$ is a linear factor of $f(x)$.

${\cal {I}}({\cal{Z}}(f))$ consists of all the functions $g\in k[x]$ such that $g$ has as it's factors, all the linear factors of $f$.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks!